# All JavaFX FXML objects null in controller

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I realise that this question has been asked before but none of the solutions have worked for me. I am starting a thread from my controller, and from there the thread gets some data from my database. The thread sends the data to my interface which is implemented in the controller. I get a null pointer exception when trying to access any of my JavaFX elements from there.

Here is my controller:

```
public class SettingsPage implements PrizeReceiver{

    @FXML
    AnchorPane settingsAnchor;
    @FXML
    ListView<String> prizeList;
    @FXML
    TextField prizeField;
    @FXML
    Button load;

    void init(AnchorPane rootPane){

       BasicConfigurator.configure();

        AnchorPane root = null;

        try {

            File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/res/settings.fxml");

        root = FXMLLoader.load(file.toURI().toURL());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (root != null) {
        rootPane.getChildren().setAll(root);
    }

    initPrizeList();

}

private void initPrizeList() {

    GetPrizesThread getPrizesThread = new GetPrizesThread(Database.firebaseDatabase, this);
    getPrizesThread.getThread().start();

}

@FXML
void addPrize(){

    Database.createPrize(prizeField.getText());

}

@Override
public void receivePrizes(ArrayList<String> prizes) {

    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    items.addAll(prizes);

    //Iv'e tried this if else with every fxml object and always prints null
    if(prizeField==null){
        System.out.println("NULL");
    }else {
        prizeList.getItems().addAll(items);
    }

}
}
```

Here is the Thread:

```
public class GetPrizesThread implements Runnable {

private boolean finished = false;

private final Thread thread;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private PrizeReceiver prizeReceiver;

GetPrizesThread(FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase, PrizeReceiver prizeReceiver){
    this.firebaseDatabase = firebaseDatabase;
    this.prizeReceiver = prizeReceiver;
    thread = new Thread(this);
}

@Override
public void run() {

    ArrayList<String> prizes = new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("prizes");

    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            HashMap map = (HashMap) snapshot.getValue();

            Set keySet = map.keySet();

            ArrayList<String> listOfKeys = new ArrayList<String>(keySet);

            prizes.clear();
            prizes.addAll(listOfKeys);

            finished = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            finished = true;
        }
    });

    while(!finished) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    prizeReceiver.receivePrizes(prizes);

}

Thread getThread() {
    return thread;
}
```

}

Here is the FXML file(built with scene builder):

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="settingsAnchor" prefHeight="454.0" prefWidth="700.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.161" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="SettingsPage">
   <children>
  <GridPane layoutX="-2.0" layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
     <children>

        <ListView fx:id="prizeList" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="246.0" GridPane.rowSpan="3">
           <GridPane.margin>
              <Insets bottom="8.0" left="8.0" right="8.0" top="8.0" />
           </GridPane.margin>
        </ListView>

        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addPrize" text="Add Prize" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
           <GridPane.margin>
              <Insets left="8.0" top="40.0" />
           </GridPane.margin>
        </Button>
        <TextField fx:id="prizeField" promptText="Prize Name" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
           <GridPane.margin>
              <Insets bottom="15.0" left="8.0" right="8.0" />
           </GridPane.margin>
        </TextField>
     </children>
  </GridPane>
```

When I don't have the if/else in place this is my error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException
at SettingsPage.receivePrizes(SettingsPage.java:74)
at GetPrizesThread.run(GetPrizesThread.java:59)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

line 74 is

> prizeList.getItems().addAll(items);

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which line is line 26 of `GetPrizesThread`?

Comment: Oops, I just realized that I posted the wrong error, I'll post the correct one

Comment: Check that you didn't import `java.awt.TextField` instead of `javafx.scene.control.TextField` in `SettingsPage` class.

Comment: Err, is it `prizeList` or `prizeField` that is `null`? Anyways, check that your controller imported the correct classes for the controls.

Comment: Also show us how that FXML is being loaded.

Comment: @Jai I'm pretty sure it's already shown (`SettingsPage.init`). Also `FXMLLoader` would complain about fields with the wrong type (= throw an exception) instead of not injecting the object.

Comment: All the imports are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A call to `SettingsPage.init` results in

```
root = FXMLLoader.load(file.toURI().toURL());
```

creating a ***new*** instance of `SettingsPage`. `FXMLLoader` automatically uses the constructor not taking parameters to create a controller instance, if the `fx:controller` attribute is present in the fxml. Objects in the fxml are injected to this new instance. However `GetPrizesThread` uses the old `SettingsPage` instance.

You can fix this by passing the controller to `FXMLLoader` before loading the fxml:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(file.toURI().toURL());
loader.setController(this);
root = loader.load();
```

You need to remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the fxml for this to work.

---

There's a different issue in your code however:

The GUI must not be accessed by threads other than the JavaFX application thread, but `GetPrizesThread` runs on a different thread. You need to do the GUI updates using `Platform.runLater` (or via some other mechanism resulting in updates running on the application thread):

```
@Override
public void receivePrizes(ArrayList<String> prizes) {
    // do update on the javafx application thread
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        prizeList.getItems().addAll(prizes);
    });
}
```